# Godot4 C# - GdUnit4 SimulateKeyPressed for SceneRunner not working

Tags: c#, unit-testing, godot, godot4

[image: GdUnit4 Test Not Working]

First I show manual `Space`, which creates 2 nodes and passes.

Then I use the `SimulateKeyPressed` on the **SceneRunner** to automate the key press, which does not create a second node. Instead I see (*no focus set*):

```
ActivateTimeFactor: Engine.TimeScale=1, Engine.PhysicsTicksPerSecond=60
set time factor: 1
set physics iterations_per_second: 60
    no focus set
    process event <Node2D#81486939523> (PlayerTests) <- Space
    no focus set
    process event <Node2D#81486939523> (PlayerTests) <- Space
```